# Connecting XBee to XBee Pro

Tags: rf, xbee, zigbee

I'm trying to wirelessly connect two modules: [XBee PRO S2C](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/digi-international/XBP24CZ7SIT-004/602-1562-ND/5322376) and [XBee S2C](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/digi-international/XB24CDMWIT-001/602-1967-ND/6226955).

Although it seems like they're connected in the software:

[image]

Serial messages between them don't go through and neither do the range test packets.

Both have the same (latest) firmware on them.

Any ideas of what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinator is in API mode.  Change to transparent mode.

If your intention is to use API mode,  append your question
and add 1) the TX frame you are sending and 2) the received 
TX status frame.

As for the range test problem, look for a RED error message
near the top of the range test panel.